# Creating a multi-panel plot of a data set grouped by two grouping variables in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, facet

I'm trying to solve the following exercise:

Make a scatter plot of the relationship between the variables 'K1' and 'K2' with "faceting" based on the parameters 'diam' and 'na' (subdivide the canvas by these two variables). Finally, assign different colors to the points depending on the 'thickness' of the ring (don't forget to factor it before). The graph should be similar to this one ("grosor" stands by "thickness"):

[image]

Now, the last code I tried with is the following one **(the dataset is called "qerat")**:
`ggplot(qerat, aes(K1,K2, fill=factor(grosor))) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(vars(diam,na))`

¿Could somebody give me a hand pointing out where the mistake is? ¡Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for a `facet_grid()` approach. Here the code using a data similar to yours:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Data
data("diamonds")
#Plot
ggplot(diamonds,aes(x=carat,y=price,color=factor(cut)))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_grid(color~clarity)
```

Output:

[image]

In the case of your code, as no data is present, I would suggest next changes:

```
#Code
ggplot(qerat, aes(K1,K2, color=factor(grosor)))+
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(diam~na)
```

Comment: ¡Thanks! The `facet_grid()` function worked and I spotted another mistake with `fill` (I changed it by `colour`.